# RubyMine shortcut to select an entire block of code

Tags: rubymine

I'm switching editors to RubyMine and I wanted to know what the easiest way to select a block of code is. I'm surprised the default shortcuts are kind of spare. Say I have this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Promotions::DarkChocolatePromotion do
  let(:multiplier) { 2 }

  it "extends Chocolate Promotion" do
    expect(described_class.singleton_class.included_modules).to include(Promotions::ChocolatePromotion)
  end

  describe ".bonuses" do
    subject { described_class.bonuses(multiplier) }
    let(:expected_bonus) { { "dark" => 2 } }

    it { is_expected.to eq(expected_bonus) }
  end
end
```

What's the easiest way to select the code from `describe ".bonueses"...` all the way down to the completing `end`?

Comment: `Edit | Extend Selection` few times in a row? If you place caret on first column on that line it should select whole method in single press (at very least it works like that with HTML/PHP code in PhpStorm).

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use the shortcut for the *Extend/Shrink Selection* action which is `Alt+Up Arrow` / `Alt+Down Arrow` on Mac and `Ctrl+W` / `Shift+Ctrl+W` on Windows and Linux. [Here's what it looks like](https://twitter.com/rubymine/status/892396352034021376).

Answer (score 0):

In a Mac its its option + Up/Down arrow

Comment: Option and Alt are the same meta key on mac keyboards.